# What's the correct way to generate a wordcloud in R?

Tags: r, text, nlp, frequency, word-cloud

My goal is to generate a wordcloud in R. But I am struggling after using 3 different methods.

**Method 1:**

```
textplot_wordcloud(dfm, min_count=20, random_order=FALSE, rotation=0.3, 
                   color=RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

I get an error saying - "could not find function textplot_wordcloud". I have quanteda, quanteda.textstats, RColorBrewer, & wordcloud libraries installed, among others. I am not sure what is wrong here in this method.

**Method 2:**

```
m <- as.matrix(dfm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m), decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word=names(v), freq=v)
head(d, 5)

set.seed(1234)
wordcloud (words=d$word, freq=d$freq, min.freq=150, max.words=150,                          random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.3, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

While I get a wordcloud, every single word in the cloud is corresponding to a rowname. So, the wordcloud has text26, text77, text75, ... and so on.
And when I look at head(d, 3), I see 'word' and 'freq' in Columns 2 & 3 as headers. Then, I see text26 text26 71 in Row 1; text77 text77 51 in Row 2; and text75 text75 50 in Row 3 ... and so on.
Somehow the rowname is showing in Column 2; and I am unsure what's wrong with my code. What am I missing?

**Method 3:**

```
wordcloud_topic <- function(topics, i) { cloud.data <- sort(topics[i, ],                                          decreasing=TRUE)[1:100]

wordcloud(names(cloud.data),
          freq=cloud.data,
          scale=c(5, 0.5),
          min.freq=30,
          rot.per=0.3,
          random.order=FALSE) }
```

Since I am a beginner, I am not sure what is wrong here in this method. I would appreciate the guidance and help here. Thank you.

Comment: To use packages you need to 1) install them (once), and 2) load them (each session you want to use them in). Try `library(quanteda)` before you run your top code, if you haven't already.

Comment: I am loading the libraries correctly as I am using it for other things and have had no issues there.

Comment: you also need the package quanteda.textplots. All the plotting has been moved to that package to simplify maintenance

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time following what's going on with your matrix, but maybe try something simpler like freq_table() from rstatix package that will take a vector and return a tibble where the word is in a column and the prop is in another column.

```
library(wordcloud)
library(rstatix)
dfm <- c("pear", "apple", "orange")
d <- freq_table(dfm)[,c(1,3)]
colnames(d) <- c("word", "freq")

wordcloud (words=d$word, freq=d$freq, min.freq=150, max.words=150, 
       random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.3, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

This works on my system without an issue with wordcloud package.

Comment: I needed to look at my matrix, thank you.

Comment: If you don't mind editing to add some sample data into your post I'm sure me or someone will take a look - use `dput()`  on your matrix, if it is too lengthy then just paste the first 10 rows.